# What's stealing my F11 key?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, openbox, lxde

I've just installed Arch Linux with LXDE and Openbox on my Asus Eee PC 1000.  I can't get my <kbd>F11</kbd> key to work in any application.  It doesn't appear to do anything when I press it.

I installed `xev`, and the <kbd>F11</kbd> key doesn't generate a KeyPress event like the other function keys do.  Here's what I get when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0xac, subw 0x0, time 11144523, (-49,121), root:(789,347),
    state 0x0, keycode 96 (keysym 0xffc9, F12), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0xac, subw 0x0, time 11144627, (-49,121), root:(789,347),
    state 0x0, keycode 96 (keysym 0xffc9, F12), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The other function keys look similar.  But here's what I get when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>:

```
FocusOut event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

In `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` I found this snippet:

```
<!--keybindings for LXPanel -->
...
<keybind key="F11">
  <action name="ToggleFullscreen"/>
</keybind>
```

But I commented that out, logged out, and logged back in.  It didn't make any difference.

How do I get my <kbd>F11</kbd> key back?  I use full screen in Firefox all the time, and I need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, it *was* the entry in  `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`.  Logging out and back in wasn't enough for some reason, but I rebooted and now my <kbd>F11</kbd> key is back in action.

Comment: OK, let me get out my crystal ball again ... Presumably due to logging in *graphically* openbox was __still active__ in the system and was in reality *not* restarted with your new settings. This would have been done by `openbox --restart`, which you can even launch from console when on LXDE "live." (as regular user!) Might save you from the trouble to reboot or even power-cycle the machine with such minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

Does <kbd>F11</kbd> work in a different window manager, like PekWM?

If it works there, but not in OpenBox, the answer to "What's stealing my <kbd>F11</kbd> key?" is "OpenBox".

Comment: I don't have any other window managers installed, but I found the solution (see my answer).

Comment: Yeah, noticed the answer right after posting. Installing a different windowmanager is easy, though, and would have helped in pinpointing the problem.